# SQLCipher: verify key against open database

Tags: c, sqlcipher

Is it possible to check if a given key is a correct decryption for already open and unlocked database?

```
#define SQLITE_HAS_CODEC
#include <sqlcipher/sqlite3.h>
#include <assert.h>

sqlite3 *open_db(void)
{
    sqlite3 *dbh;

    sqlite3_open_v2("test.db", &dbh, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);
    sqlite3_key(dbh, "xxxx", 4);

    return dbh;
}

int key_is_valid(sqlite3 *dbh, const char *key)
{
    /* ??? */
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sqlite3 *dbh = open_db();

    assert(key_is_valid(dbh, "test"));
    assert(!key_is_valid(dbh, "foobar"));

    return 0;
}
```

I know I could store decryption key passed to `sqlite3_key` for later verification, but I'd like to avoid it.

The reason I need to do this is that I want to allow users to change password, and before that I want them to provide old one.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the password provided is valid following the keying of the database by attempting to read from the `sqlite_master` table:

`SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master;`

The library requires the correct password is provided before changing the password. Once you have properly keyed the database, you can change the password using the following API:

`int sqlite3_rekey(sqlite3 *db, const void *pKey, int nKey);`